# Panda Dataframe: Iterate over column header and corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a key-value pair for a df column header and Row 0 values.

But with the below code I get

**ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

```
Firm |Price |Revenue | Cost|
A    | 3    |4       |  5  |

 pt=[]
 pt=[(k, l) for k in df.columns[2:4] and l in df.iloc[0,2:4]]
 pt_dict=dict(pt)
```

**Required Output**

```
{Revenue: 4, Cost: 5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pt_dict = dict(zip(df.columns[2:4], df.iloc[0, 2:4]))
```

Output:

```
{Revenue: 4, Cost: 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example that work if you want just one row.

```
data = {'Firm': ["A"], 'price': [3], "Revenue":[4], "Cost":[5]}
t = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
cols = ["Revenue", "Cost"]
t.loc[0,cols].to_dict()
```

If you one more than row, the dict put [row:value] in the value of the dict